# Does Allah create the movements in our bodies every moment?

Tags: allah, human-body

At every second we change our movements Does Allah create the movements in our bodies every moment Or, are our bodies programmed? Do they work on their own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allah create our whole body and they put brain in our head which works like a machine when our whole body sleep only our brain awake our brain control our whole body due to brain our body work because brain send message to our whole body .That's why we change our movements every single moment.Allah create our whole body and set program in our body so every second we change our movements because program is set in our body.